# No qualifying bean of type for 2 external maven dependencies

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, autowired

I'm working on a Spring Boot project that includes 2 maven dependencies, those dependencies both use `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate` so when in my project I do:

```
@Autowired
AClassUsingRestTemplate object;
```

it triggers:

```
No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: externalDependencyOneRestTemplate,externalDependencyTwoRestTemplate
```

I have the control of only one of those dependencies, where I've defined:

```
@Bean(name = "externalDependencyOneRestTemplate")
    public RestTemplate buildExternalDependencyOneRestTemplate() {
        final HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory =
                new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClientBuilder.create().build());

        final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(restTemplate.getRequestFactory()));

        return restTemplate;
    }
```

what can I do to fix it?

Do I have to tell `ClassUsingRestTemplate` to use a specifi `RestTemplate` implementations? If yes, how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify which one you want using `@Qualifier`:

```java
@Autowired
@Qualifier("externalDependencyOneRestTemplate")
RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

If you cannot modify the code depending on the `RestTemplate`, you can specify which one is the default, i.e. which one to use if `@Qualifier` is not specified:

```java
@Primary
@Bean(name = "externalDependencyOneRestTemplate")
public RestTemplate buildExternalDependencyOneRestTemplate() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Adding `@Primary` to the bean I created in the dependency that I control just did the trick for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Spring has found 2 types of beans it can inject in this Autowired member: "externalDependencyOneRestTemplate"
or "externalDependencyTwoRestTemplate".

Spring cannot choose because it doesn't read your mind. You must help Spring by specifying which bean you want by using the Qualifier annotation:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("nameOfMyBeanHere")
AClassUsingRestTemplate object;
```

Additionally, it doesn't look like your RestTemplate implementation does anything special, i would suggest enabling Spring Autoconfiguration (which automatically creates a RestTemplate bean) and injecting it instead of creating your own.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `@Qualifier` approach mentioned by Andreas, there are two marginally better options with Boot:

1. If your class is Spring-aware, inject `RestTemplateBuilder` instead of a `RestTemplate`, and use that for your customization. This allows for application-level configuration (e.g., adding authentication and tracing interceptors), and then further configuration on the specific service level (converters, failure handlers).
2. Use `@Bean` to configure your `AClassUsingRestTemplate`, passing a `RestTemplate` to its constructor. (Constructor injection is recommended over field injection.) In `@Bean`, you can do whatever custom setup you want.

Comment: The idea of using `RestTemplateBuilder` is very good, next time I'll do it, thanks